# How to user RxJava's ConcatArray to show users at first from Database, and then from Webservice

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, android-room

> Task: Show list of users in the `ListView` -> at first show users from
>   `Database` (DB is `Room`) and then if there are answer from `API` (`@GET` request using `Retrofit2`) show
>   fetched data.

I thought that to implement this feature i need to use `RxJava`'s `ConcatArray` method.

So in my `Activity` I have method that fetches data:

```
public Observable<List<User>> getUsers() {
    return Observable.concatArray(
        getUsersFromDB(),
        getUsersFromApi()
    );
}

private Observable<List<User>> getUsersFromDB() {
    return userDAO.getUsers().toObservable();
}

private Observable<List<User>> getUsersFromApi() {
    return api.getUsers()
        .doOnNext(users -> cacheUsers(users));
}
```

It's working, when Internet Connection is OK, but it has a bug, which I can't fix; bug can be reproduce like this:

> 1. Run Activity (App) with the Internet connection
> 2. Close Activity (App)
> 3. Run Activity (App) without Internet

As result data that in DB not showing, but It's there, cached, I think It's because in `ConcatArray` in `getUsersFromApi()` error occur and it clears fetched data from DB.

Could you help me please?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I think the problem is that the concatenated observable fails if any of the operands fails. You can use onErrorResumeNext as explained in this article: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always getting data from DB and API in this case.When you don't have the internet connection you're receiving the exception.

You can use couple solutions. First one is flat map

```
getUsersFromDB().flatMap(list -> {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return getUsersFromApi();
        } else {
            return Observable.just(list);
        }
    }).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

or the second one is concat + filter + first

```
Observable.concat(getUsersFromApi(), getUsersFromApi())
    .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
    .first(Collections.emptyList())
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

An Exception is thrown when there's no Internet Connection. You can utilize the onErrorResumeNext operator to return the cached data instead.

```java
public Observable<List<User>> getUsers() {
    return Observable.concatArray(
        getUsersFromDB().take(1),
        getUsersFromApi()
    ).onErrorResumeNext(getUsersFromDB());
}
```